# How to display a specific sheet from the VBA editor window

Tags: show, display

I want to activate my sheet "feuil2" with  the following code that I run from the VBA editor.

```
Sub display()
    Workbooks("intro.xlsm").Sheets("Feuil2").Activate
End Sub
```

I press F5 to run this macro, but the VB editor remains in the foreground and I don't see the sheet "feuil2"
I also tried with "select", and with "visible=yes" but it does not work better.
I also tried from the immediate window: doesn't work!
Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance